# How to use Studio to sum all in field and display in List view in Odoo 13 enterprise?

Tags: listview, formview, odoo-13

I would like to display the sum (1.png) and the dropdown history of an object (2.png) in a related field in the list view:

(1.png):
[image: Display Sum all of an object in (Mức đóng BHXH) field]

(2.png):
[image: Display dropdown list of an object's history in (Mức dóng BHXH) field]

How can I use Studio of Odoo 13 enterprise to do that?

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- Create List View
- on Fields you can set Properties/Aggregate value (eg SUM)
- Then create `Group by` rules For the Search

Comment: Hello Paxmees, Thanks for your help. Yes. I see.